# Display pricing with options

Tags: pricing

I make a website for a recording studio that provides about 15 services. Each service can be "customized" with options (depending about the quantity of days, the work to do...).

For the moment, I made a kind of list with details on click on an element. 
[image]

I am wondering what is the best way to make this quickly clear without being too "commercial".

Comment: Your question comes across as a site review - which isn't allowed.  Please think of the specific UX problem that you have and rephrase the question to focus on that, rather than a broad "how can I make this better" sort of question.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question, I think it's good now

Answer (score 3):

I think you're already well on your way.
15 services + options is a lot and I think your mockup is already pretty clear.
It's hard to circumvent the issue that it will be quite a list.
To add on this concept I would advice some sort of counter that keeps track of the price /hour with every option selected.
With the starting amount of €12/hour and two options +€1/hour each, the counter would say €14/hour.

I don't know if this is at all possible, but you could turn it all the way around and instead of providing solutions for the visitor to decide which fits best with their problem, you could let the visitor select their problem and provide them with the fitting solution.

Perhaps there are fewer problems then there are solutions (services).

For example:
Problem/need: "I need a radio commercial"
Solution: Service #1 and Service #3